# mysql table exist logic inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
  DECLARE FoundCount INT;
  DECLARE db_Name VARCHAR(255);

SET @Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val, '_List');
SET @db_Name='test_rs';

   SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) INTO', @FoundCount ,'
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema =',@db_Name,'
    AND table_name =', @Project_List_val);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF FoundCount = 1 THEN
SET @sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO test (Panel_Id)
                    SELECT Panel_Id 
                    FROM ', @Project_List_val);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
```

This Stored procedure executed fine. But when tried to run it it is showing below error.

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

I need to run second query if the specified table (@Project_List_val) exist.

Answer (score 0):

check condition like this  @FoundCount=1 like this

Try this

-- DECLARE FoundCount INT;

```
 DECLARE db_Name VARCHAR(255);

SET @Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val, '_List');
SET @db_Name='test_rs';

   SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ', @FoundCount ,'
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = ',@db_Name,'
    AND table_name =', @Project_List_val);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    IF @FoundCount = 1 THEN
SET @sql = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO test (Panel_Id)
                    SELECT Panel_Id 
                    FROM ', @Project_List_val);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
```

use like this :

```
SET @sql1 = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(1) INTO ', @FoundCount ,'
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = ',@db_Name,'
    AND table_name =', @Project_List_val);
```

i have give space after into .copy this and tel me

Comment: did you put the space after into clause

Comment: i find it from were Project_Number_val value coming >?

Comment: SET @Project_List_val = CONCAT(Project_Number_val, '_List'); is not getting contacting that y found count will not update

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24370/discussion-between-user1597811-and-user2001117)

Answer (score 0):

Yes resolved. The single quotes missing for those variables inside statement for @db_Name and @Project_List_Val